# How to instantiate contents of rendered template_file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a template file that I use to on a list:

```
variable "users" {
  type = "list"
  default = [
    "blackwidow",
    "hulk",
    "marvel",
  ]
}

// This will loop through the users list above and render out code for
// each item in the list.
data "template_file" "init" {
  template = file("user_template.tpl")
  count = length(var.users)
  vars = {
    username = var.users[count.index]
    bucketid = aws_s3_bucket.myFTP_Bucket.id
  }
}
```

The template file has multiple aws resources like
 - "aws_transfer_user"
 - "aws_s3_bucket_object"
 - "aws_transfer_ssh_key"
etc...  In fact it can have more stuff than just that. It also has some terraform variables in there too.

This data template works great in rendering out the contents of the template file, substituting in the names of my users.

*But* that's all terraform does.

Terraform doesn't instantiate the rendered content of the template file. It just merely keeps it as a string and keeps it in memory. Kind of like the C preprocessor doing substitution, but not 'including' the file.
Kind of frustrating. I'd like Terraform to instantiate the contents of my rendered template file. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `template_file` data source (along with the [`templatefile`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/functions/templatefile.html) function that has replaced it for Terraform 0.12) are for string templating, not for modular Terraform configuration.

To produce a set of different resource instances per item in a collection, we use [resource `for_each`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#for_each-multiple-resource-instances-defined-by-a-map-or-set-of-strings):

```
variable "users" {
  type = set(string)
  default = [
    "blackwidow",
    "hulk",
    "marvel",
  ]
}

resource "aws_transfer_user" "example" {
  for_each = var.users

  # ...
}

resource "aws_transfer_user" "example" {
  for_each = var.users

  # ...
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_object" "example" {
  for_each = var.users

  # ...
}

resource "aws_transfer_ssh_key" "example" {
  for_each = aws_transfer_user.example

  # ...
}
```

Inside each of those resource blocks you can use `each.key` to refer to each one of the usernames. Inside the `resource "aws_transfer_ssh_key" "example"` block, because I used `aws_transfer_user.example` as the repetition expression, you can also use `each.value` to access the attributes of the corresponding `aws_transfer_user` object. That `for_each` expression also serves to tell Terraform that `aws_transfer_ssh_key.example` depends on `aws_transfer_user.example`.

Comment: Ok, I've read the docs on this, and this is nice. I think it will work well. Then I don't need a syntax-free template document anymore, and it seems this will give me less code too. Very nice.

Comment: Thanks, I implemented your suggestion this morning (after upgrading terraform), and it worked great.